# import junit jupiter api not found

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, junit

I am using Junit to test some code in a Maven project in Netbeans. The dependency specified is Junit 4.12 (in the pom.xml).

However, I am getting a compiler error when I try and build:

`error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist`

on this line:
`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

I suspect it is a Junit4/Junit5 thing, since when I open an older version of the project in IntelliJ, it lists Junit5 as a dependency. Should I just use Junit5?

Any help in resolving the build error would be appreciated!

Answer (score 18):

You need to Inject `jupiter` artefact before start writing Tests

```
Group ID: org.junit.jupiter
Artifact ID: junit-jupiter-api
Version: 5.0.0-M5
```

`JUnit Jupiter` is submodule of `JUnit 5` so you need to use JUnit 5

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I currently have:
`<dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>`

Comment: However, I'm still getting the same error as before

Comment: Sorry, I meant I changed it to what you said

Comment: Why does this dependency needs to be included separately? Why isn't the junit dependency enough?

Answer (score 6):

In my case it worked by adding this line in app: build.gradle

```
dependencies {  
implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.1'
}
```

Comment: "Failed to resolve: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter" :-/

Comment: it should be `testImplementation` instead of `implementation `

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem related to the `<scope>test</scope>`

Your test class should be in the test package.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Your test should be here

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Another thing I noticed is when using the IntelliJ "Create Test" function (Alt + Enter from the class for which you want to create a test), if you don't already have a test directory in your project, IntelliJ will drop the test class into your source (main) directory instead - which is pretty unexpected (instead of just creating the test dir for you). From there (main) of course your dependencies scoped in your pom as "test" won't be accessible. Wonder if this was part of the OP's issue, as it was for me.